# "The local variable may not have been initialized"

Tags: java

```
 // getAccount() retrieves an account based on customer number
 public String getAccount(String customerNumber) {
      int count;
      for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length - 1; i++) {
           if (accounts[i].getAccountNumber().equals(customerNumber)) {
                break;
           }
           count = i;
      }
      return accounts[***count***].toString(); 
 }
```

I'm writing a bank app for class and this `getAccount()` function loops through the array of accounts, and compares it with the value it is provided and breaks out of that loop once it finds the correct account and stores that index value in `count`, in order to return the customer details using `count` as the index value, but the last return statement is giving me the error in the title. I have it initialized in the top of the code so I'm confused.

Comment: Actually, there is a code path that can cause `count` to be uninitialized; if `accounts.length` is zero, the loop body will never execute, and `count` will never get set.  Write `int count = 0;` and the warning will disappear.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I have it initialized in the top of the code_ If you are referring to this line of code (in your question): `int count;` then it is **not** initialized.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Even if length is 1.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop condition is `i < accounts.length - 1`.
So, if `accounts.length` is 0 (or 1), the condition is `i < -1` (or `i < 0`). And `i` starts at 0. Therefore the for loop exits right away without ever encountering the `count = i;`.

Also, if the very first account at index 0 fulfills the condition, you break before ever reaching the `count = i;`.

So, there is a possibility (in fact, multiple) that the code ends up at the `return` without ever setting `count` to a value. Java compiler correctly detects it and complains.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you seem to assume that `int count;` initializes the count, but it does not work that way. You just *declared* it. Initializing means assigning a value for the first time, doing that `=`. Just actually initialize it where you declare it `int count = 0;`

Also, the code does not do what you think it does. It does **not** return the right account as you `break` out of the loop before setting `count` to the right `i`. You will thus return the account one index *below* the one you wanted.

Correct code would be something along the lines of

```java
public String getAccount(String customerNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
         if (accounts[i].getAccountNumber().equals(customerNumber)) {
              // yes, you can return from inside the loop as well, no need to store the result and return outside
              return accounts[i].toString();
         }
    }
    return ""; // change to your favorite 'not found' value, for example null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse between **declaration** and **initialization**.
At the top of the method, you declare a variable int count, but don't initialize it to any value.

When return is reached, it's indeed possible that the value of count stays undefined. Most obvious cases include:

- If accounts is empty
- If `accounts[0]` is the right account, `count=i` is never reached

Hence the error message.

In C/C++, there wouldn't be any error, but the value could be anything totally unexpected. In Java, being in such an undefined state is unacceptable, so the compiler doesn't let you go. You can declare a local variable without initializing it only if the compiler can be sure that, whatever the code path followed, it has got a well-defined value when it is read.

You can easily fix your code by initializing count to 0 right at declaration. Local variables aren't initialized to 0 or null by default, only member variables are.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your `count` variable to zero before the loop because, if the collection happens to have no items, the code in the loop will never get executed and the variable will remain uninitialized by the time it reaches the line that reads it.

Answer (score -1):

You have not initialized local count variable. Once initialized error will not come.